# Как работает код [i for i in range(51) if i % 2 == 0]?

Tags: python, массивы

```
evens_to_50 = [i for i in range(51) if i % 2 == 0]
print evens_to_50
```

Этот код генерирует список из четных чисел до пятидесяти.
Но мне, как новому в программировании непонятны некоторые моменты - :

1. Почему генерация происходит в квадратных скобках, их же обычно
   используют при работе с индексами
2. Что делает первая **i** перед циклом **for**? Почему после **range(51)** нет двоеточия и перевода на новую линию с табулированием?
3. Где еще могут использоваться квадратные скобки?
4. В квадратных скобках можно сколько угодно **if** или **for** писать? Какие в них правила?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Эта конструкция называется "генератор". Это способ в одну строку создать список (массив), наполненный значениями. Двоеточия нет именно потому, что это не цикл `for`, а генератор. Давайте разберем подробно:

```
[i for i in range(51) if i % 2 == 0]
```

или в более общем виде:

```
[expr(variable) for variable in iterable if condition(variable)]
```

Здесь:

- `iterable` — некий объект, из которого можно один за другим получать значения (пока не кончатся). Список, кортеж или, например, ключи словаря. Отсюда поштучно берутся значения и присваиваются переменной `variable`. Поочередные операции называются "итерациями", а вышеописанный объект — [итерируемым (iterable)](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable).

  Выражение `range(51)` возвращает список натуральных чисел от 0 до 50 включительно. Их мы и перебираем.
- `variable` (имя произвольное) — просто переменная, поочередно принимающая все значения из `iterable`. Работает точно так же, как счетчик в цикле.
- `expr(variable)` — любая функция, которая возвращает значение. Она может принимать аргументом `variable`, может что угодно ещё, может вообще ничего не принимать. Понятно, что `i` возвращает просто значение `i` в неизменном виде. Возвращаемые этой функцией значения становятся элементами генерируемого списка. Другие примеры:

  - `[i**2 for i in range(51)]` – квадраты чисел
  - `[0 for i in range(51)]` – просто заполняем нулями
- `condition(variable)` — необязательное условие. Если оно присутствует, то в полученный список войдут только те значения, для которых `condition(variable) == True`. Можно написать одно `if`, но внутри может быть сколь угодно сложное выражение, т.е. `if a(i) and b(i) or c(i)...`

  В данном случае выбираются те числа, которые кратны двум (т.е. чётные).

Answer (score 3):

Вот эквивалент:

```
evens_to_50 = list()
for i in range(51):
   if i % 2 == 0:
      evens_to_50 += [i]
```

Если хочешь лучше разобраться в основах Python, то советую пойти [сюда.](https://stepic.org/) Там есть отличные курсы в которых подробно это объясняется.

По поводу скобок. Это специальная штука, которая встроена в сам язык. Называется list comprehension и являетсся способом создания списка "на лету"(ведь в квадратных скобках всегда содержется список), т.е. возможность объявить содержимое списка прямо внутри списка

Это все основано на механизме итератеров. Если интересно, можешь посмотреть мой конспект, там коротко есть об этом. [Лови](https://github.com/Faoxis/PythonBasicAndApplication/blob/master/week2/3.%20Iterators%20and%20generators.ipynb). Только просьба не винить меня в грамотических ошибках. :)

И еще. У тебя в метках стоит слово "массив". Но тут получается не массив как в С или Java, а список. Массив и список - разные вещи и это очень важно.

Comment: не эквивалент, у вас вывода нет

Comment: Действительно не принтанул )

Comment: Вот этот код мне вполне понятен, я так же понял что в моем примере код делает тоже самое, мне непонятны правила того, как мой код составлен - почему квадратные скобки, почему i перед for,  почему нет двоеточий. табуляций и прочего.

Comment: @Yahya Прекракрасно понимаю, по началу это кажется магией какой-то... :) Сверху я дополнил ответ пояснениями.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(*(i for i in range(51) if not i % 2))
print({i for i in range(51) if not i % 2})
print({i: i for i in range(51) if not i % 2})
print([i if not i % 2 else '*' for a in range(51) for i in range(a) if a > 22])
```