# Для чего в строке используются квадратные скобки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
h1,m1,s1,h2,m2,s2 = [int(input()) for i in 'aaaaaa']
print((h2-h1)*3600+(m2-m1)*60+(s2-s1))
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как работает код \[i for i in range(51) if i % 2 == 0\]?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/551990/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-i-for-i-in-range51-if-i-2-0)

Answer (score 6):

Тут выражение генератора списка:

```
h1,m1,s1,h2,m2,s2 = [int(input()) for i in 'aaaaaa']
```

У него вид: `[<значение_элемента_списка> for <значение_из_итератора> in <итератор>]` (после `<итератор>` еще можно написать условие типа `... in <итератор> if <условие>]`).

Т.е. тут говорится следующее:

- Сделай итерацию по строке `'aaaaaa'`
- На каждую итерацию считай вводимое значение и приведи его к числу `int(input())`
- Полученные числа сохрани в списке
- Сделай распаковку элементов списка в переменные слева

---

**Другое дело,** что это можно было сделать проще, без использования ненужных элементов:

```
[int(input()) for _ in range(6)]
```

Строка `'aaaaaa'` нужна была только для того, чтобы 6 раз вызвать `int(input())`, поэтому ее убираем и ставим `range(6)`, а т.к. `i` тоже не используется, то вместо него ставим символ-заменитель `_`

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @Ann_S123, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 3):

Вы выражение в квадратных скобках это генератор списка.
Чтобы было код стал более читаемым его можно развернуть примерно так:

```py
l = []
for i in range(6):
    l.append(int(input()))
    
h1,m1,s1,h2,m2,s2 = l
print((h2-h1)*3600+(m2-m1)*60+(s2-s1))
```

Comment: спасибо большое